# Shared module with angular d'ont work

Tags: angular

In fact I have 2 modules in my application apart from the main module:
- A module called Global.module: which contains sharable modules;
- And the other module called Pages.modules which contains my pages;
I want the modules in the global.module to be visible by pages.modules;
The problem I encountered that with the page module fails to retrieve the existing modules in Global.module see my source code; I also try exports: [NgaModule.forRoot ()] on modules to share but it seems that exports does not support ModuleWithProviders

Global.module

```
export const MODULES=[ BrowserModule,
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  NavbarModule,
  FooterModule,
  SidebarModule,
  RouterModule,
  LbdModule,ModalModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, ToastModule,NgbModule,
  FroalaEditorModule,
  FroalaViewModule,
  AceEditorModule,UiSwitchModule,TooltipModule,ChartsModule]
  export const SERVICES=[
    RouteGuard,BsModalService,LynkService,SharedService,Data,{provide: ToastOptions, useClass: CustomOption}, {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: interceptorFactory,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ServerUrlInterceptorService] 
    } ,ServerUrlInterceptorService 
  ]
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    ...MODULES
  ]

})
export class GlobalModule { 
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return <ModuleWithProviders> {
      ngModule: GlobalModule,
      providers: [
        ...SERVICES
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Pages.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, routing,FormsModule,GlobalModule],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    DefaultComponent,
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {
}
```

App.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
....
,GlobalModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: what specific error message do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You can not export modules, which you didn't import before.

You will have to add
`imports: [ ... MODULES ]`
to your GlobalModule.

Comment: I added it but it tells me that some modules are not yet existing